# Can SAS Tape Drive (HP StoreEver 6250) used with LSI SAS 9200-8e-HP?

Tags: sas, tape, tapedrive

I plan to buy secondhand [HP StoreEver 6250](https://www.tokopedia.com/maxstore1-1/hp-storeever-lto-6-ultrium-6250-external-tape-drive-eh970a-lto6) tape drive for backup purpose, but not sure what SAS Card that are compatible with that device and works on ubuntu seamlessly.
One of the SAS card that I saw from the same seller is [LSI SAS 9200-8e-HP](https://www.tokopedia.com/maxstore1-1/lsi-sas-9200-8e-hp-8-port-dual-port-6gbps-sas-sata-hba-raid-controller), would that work properly?

Comment: This tape is generation 6 LTO and this generation was introduced in 2012. So you are limited with gen 6 and gen 5 tapes you can use. And current generation of LTO is 9. So old tapes will not be available on the market shortly.

Comment: nobody selling cheap lto-8 drive here, there's one but it 2U size, '__')

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Both are older 6 Gb/s SAS, both come from the same vendor (HP).

https://www.storagereview.com/review/hp-storeever-lto-6-ultrium-6250-review-eh970a

https://docs.broadcom.com/doc/12352378

I believe you’re good to go!

Comment: I ended up buying whatever the seller give, one that he already tested XD

Comment: Good choice for sure!